# How to Change QMessageBox Icon and Title

Tags: c++, qt, qmessagebox

I am creating a ui app with *Qt c++*.

I have a `error` message that I have created by using `QMessageBox` Class like :

```
QMessageBox errorMessage;
errorMessage.critical(0, "Error", "An error has occured !");
errorMessage.setFixedSize(500, 200);
```

It is like:

[image]

And I want to change the red circled things which are the icon and the title.

[image]

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#icon-prop, http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#iconPixmap-prop

Comment: I have already checked the documentation before asking the question, I would be glad if you can provide me with a working code snippet because it is not working when I use setIcon or setWindowIcon or setPixmap etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

However you can use of `QMessageBox::critical(0, "Error", "An error has occured !");` because `critical(...)` method is `static` and theres no need for create an instance of `QMessageBox`.

Use bellow `code` :

```
QMessageBox mb("Application Name",
                           "Hardware failure.\n\nDisk error detected\nDo you want to stop?",
                           QMessageBox::NoIcon,
                           QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::Default,
                           QMessageBox::NoButton,
                           QMessageBox::NoButton);

QPixmap exportSuccess("/media/msi/Information/Pictures/Icons/Icons Pack/PNG/48X48/about.png");
mb.setIconPixmap(exportSuccess);
mb.exec();
```

[image]

This example work 100%

Comment: Thanks!, it worked like a charm. But your exportSuccess part is the icon that is the blue circled 'i' at your example.

Comment: @BerkUtkuYenisey your welcome, yes you can change it arbitrary with your icon.

Comment: No I have done that already :D. But which part of the code should I change to change the Icon that I have encircled with red pen at my example.(That is near the application Name)?

Comment: @BerkUtkuYenisey its very simple, just add `QPixmap`  then call `setIconPixmap` from your `QMessageBox` instance, finally call `exec` method from it.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to set the icon for every window you can do so globally with this:

```
QApplication::setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/GuiMain/gh_resource/GH Icon.ico"));
```

You also aren't required to use pixmap in my experience, you can use:

```
mb.setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/path/to/icon.ico"));
```

This will work on individual message boxes, just add your custom icon to your .qrc file

Answer (score 3):

Simply you can set Icon for your Application it will automatically set on your MessegeBox